# Equivalent of py:strip for Mako?

Tags: python, pyramid, template-engine, mako, genshi

I'm converting a bunch of Genshi templates to Mako.

I tend to use this in Genshi a lot:

```
<span class="special" py:strip="challenge">Company</span>
```

What this does in Genshi is strip the class tags and just leave the bare word Company when challenge is true.

What's the best way to do this in Mako?

I've come up with

```
   % if not challenge:
       <span class="special">
   % endif   
   Company
   % if not challenge:
       </span>
   % endif
```

But two control structures seems like one to many.

Or this

```
% if not challenge:
  <span class="special">Company</span>
% else:
  Company
% endif
```

This is only one control structure but I repeat the word company twice. That's not bad here, but it will be ugly when I have something much larger than the word Company in the span.

There has to be an elegant equivalent to py:strip for Mako, no?

Answer (score 1):

A Mako [Def](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#using-defs) might help you. It allow some king of "function" to be defined an the applied to contents multiple times throughout the template.

The most useful way to use a Def may be a [Def with embedded contents](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#calling-a-def-with-embedded-content-and-or-other-defs), which allows code like

```
<%self:buildtable>
    I am the table body.
</%self:buildtable>
```

An then process the content as defined in the Def.

Answer (score -1):

There is no equivalent for py:strip in Mako. Because Mako operates on bytes, not html/xml tags.

Pyramid, besides Mako, comes with Chameleon(XML/HTML template engine like Genshi). In Chameleon it would be:

```
<span class="special" tal:omit-tag="challenge">Company</span>
```